Cannot delete cookie
I want to delete a cookie when a specific url is requested by the browser: /logout.
To do so, I created a page.tsx with the following code:
"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import {redirect} from "next/navigation";

export default async function Page() {
    cookies().delete('auth-token');

    redirect('/');
}

When I try to open the logout url in the browser, I get the following error:
Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler.

How can I fix this?

why you dont creating a server action for do that?

I tried this, got the same error.

add route.ts in /logout instead of page.tsx. or use the server action in a client component.
